# How to serialize a data class in Android Kotlin using moshi

Tags: android, json, kotlin, parcelable, moshi

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Note(val name)
```

Do I need to parcelize the above model I am using Moshi and change it to something like

```
@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Note(val name) : Parcelable
```

Why do we even need to parcelize this data class?

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to add `@Parcelize`, but you may want to add the `@Json` annotation to the field. Also, you were missing the type of the property `name`.

```kotlin
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Note(
    @field:Json(name = "name")
    val name: String
)
```